# ListView onListItemClick not functioning correctly

Tags: android, listview, toast

I have a ListView of items. When I click on an item I want to display a simple toast message to inform user of the item clicked. However for some reason the code below is not working for me:

Code from current project: - not working.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + " added to order", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

It's very strange as it has worked in the past. Each item in the list contains an ImageView, two TextViews, a Button and one NumberPicker widget. They all function correctly but for some reason the onListItemClick() code is not executed.

Any ideas as to why? Many thanks!

EDIT: I just checked over an older project whereby I used similar code, tested it and it worked fine, I cant figure out why I am having this issue, is it something to do with the complexity of the view??

Below is code from a previous project: - Worked fine.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + " added to order", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // add clicked item to orderData....
    MenuItem m = (MenuItem) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
    // create new item
    orderData.add(m);
    subTotal += m.getPrice();
    calc();
}
```

EDIT: getView() method of Adapter class

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View v = convertView;

    if(v == null){
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.menuitem_row, null);
    }

    //assign values to view
    final MenuItem item = this.menuItems.get(position);

    TextView nameView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    final TextView priceView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_price);

    nameView.setText(item.getName() + " ");
    priceView.setText("€"+ String.valueOf(item.getPrice()));

    //number picker
    np = (NumberPicker)v.findViewById(R.id.numpick);
    np.setMaxValue(99);
    np.setMinValue(0);
    np.setValue(0);

    //calculation occurs when values are changed...
    np.setOnValueChangedListener( new OnValueChangeListener() {
          public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                Toast.makeText(picker.getContext(), "dish: " + item.getName() + " amount: " + picker.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(picker.getContext(), "new Value: " + newVal + " old Value: " + oldVal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               // amount += item.getPrice() * picker.getValue();

                if(newVal > oldVal){
                    total = (item.getPrice() * newVal) - item.getPrice() * oldVal;
                    amount += total;
                }

                if(newVal < oldVal){
                    total = (item.getPrice() * oldVal) - item.getPrice() * newVal;
                    amount -= total;
                }

                price.setText("€" + String.valueOf(amount));
            }
          });

    return v;

}
```

Menu_item_row.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numpick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dishpic"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/numpick"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/reviewBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/item_price"
        android:text="ITEM NAME"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/reviewBtn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dishpic"
        android:text="ITEM PRICE"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reviewBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dishpic"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/numpick"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dishpic"
        android:text="@string/reviewBtn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sometimes having something that also needs user input (such as your picker) interferes with `onListItemClick()`.

Comment: I thought that may be the problem, Is there anything I can do to solve that? Or perhaps I will have to add the Toast when the picker is changed...

Comment: Do you call `setContentView()` or use the default ListView?

Comment: You should be using `this` or `getContext()` instead of `getApplicationContext()`...

Comment: @Sam I call the setContentView() method in the onCreate() - setContentView(R.layout.activity_starters). I then use a custom array adapter for each view of the list.

Comment: To be clear, are you using only one ListView with the id `@android:id/list` or more? Do you call `setOnItemClickListener()`?

Comment: @Sam Yes, I am using only one ListView with the id  `@android:id/list`. I do not call the `setOnItemClickListener()`. I will try that now.

Comment: my class extends to ListActivity. So surely there is no need to set a listener in this way?

Comment: You don't need to (it is an either / or situtation, you cannot use both). I'm just convering the basics since you haven't posted this code. One more general question: are you assign any touch listeners to the rows (OnClickListener, OnLongClick, etc)?

Comment: I will put the code up if you would like to see. I am assigning a listener to the NumberPicker using `setOnValueChangedListener`.

Comment: Ok, that looks fine... Aside from the Button and NumberPicker are any of your Views in `menuitem_row.xml` clickable or focusable? (This will intercept the touch event before it reaches `onListItemClick()`.)

Comment: No, nothing else is clickable or focusable, in fact I haven't event set this attribute for any of the elements.

Comment: All of the code I see looks fine. You should watch a Google I/O [talk](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) or two to learn about ViewHolders, but this shouldn't stop the Toast from displaying...

Comment: Yeah, It's strange. I think what your saying about the clickable and focusable attributes combined with @A--C answer about the NumberPicker interfering with the input may have something to do with it!

Comment: When I wanted to put a checkbox into a listview for my app I ended up taking the Android alarm source code, finding the layout and seeing how that worked. It has a root linearlayout, a checkbox then another linearlayout that contains everything else. Try using a LinearLayout instead of a RelativeLayout. I can't make any guarantees though.

Answer (score 1):

Try for `Button` and `NumberPicker` to call `setFocus(false)` in `getView()`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

Just remove the Button and NumberPicker from the listRow and see whether its working or not. If it is working then that behaviour should be because of the View.

In presence of the Button and NumberPicker, you are not able to click on the ListviewItem that's why you are not getting any toast.

So, Please try that and let me know.

Feel free for any comments.

Comment: Thats a good point, I'm not at my computer now but will give that a shot as soon as I can!